# Using a different tense in a dependent clause?

Tags: tenses

Using a different tense in a dependent clause? Is this allowed and when?

> She **ignored** everything, even the thumping doors as people **slam**
> them.

Even the thumping doors as people slam them is a dependent clause, but slam is in the present, so I am wondering if this is allowed. I am thinking it is, but I am not sure why. Is there any rule that allows us to mix present with past?

Answer (score 1):

Normally, when the main clause is past, verbs in any dependent clause are backshifted (to past, unless they were already past, in which case they will usually be shifted to past perfect).

There  is an exception, where what is stated in the subordinate clause is timeless, or still continuing:

> He said that he was/is living in London now.

If he is still living in London now, then either *is* or *was* is possible.

But your example sentence would be very unusual: the only reading that makes any sense is that people have continued to slam the doors right up to the present.

Comment: Yes. Doorslamming doubtless is with us still, but this implies a specific, probably coordinated,  activity. A slam-a-thon.